# Ruby: How to exit a function and then return to it

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a text-adventure game for exercise 36 of Learn Ruby the hard Way:  http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex36.html

I want to include 'instructions' as an option players can use anytime, but once the player exits the Room() function and enters the intructions() function, I am unsure how to return them to the appropriate room. I can have the instructions() always return player to the start after, but is there a way to get them back to the same location?

Here is a quick example, sorry it's incomplete...I'm still in the middle of building it:

```
puts
puts <<INTRO
"Welcome to the Cave of Indifference.
It doesn't much care for you. Beware!
There are deadly areas of this cave, but if you seek
it you may find the secret treasure and escape with your life."
INTRO
puts
puts "Type \'Instructions\' at any time for direction"
puts

sword = false
monster = true
treasure = false

def Command()
    puts ">>> "
end

def dead(how)
    puts how.to_s
    puts "PLAYER DEAD!"
    Process.exit(0)
end

def instruction()
    puts "Rooms will have individual instructions"
    puts "but here are some general items."
    puts "west, east, north, south: goes that direction"
    puts "look: look around the room"
    puts "take: to take item or object"
end

def Room1()
    puts "You are now at the cave entrance."
    puts "You may go west or east. OR exit with your life!"
    Command(); choice = gets.chomp()

    if choice.downcase == "exit" && treasure = true
        puts "Congratulations! You win!"
        Process.break
    elsif choice.downcase == "exit" && treasure = false
        puts "Seriously?! Giving up already?"
        puts "Fine. Here is what happens:"
        dead("You stumble on your exit from the cave and trip
        on a rock. The fall cracks your skull and you bleed
        to death. Bye bye!")
    elsif choice.downcase.include? "right"
        #INPUT
    elsif choice.downcase.include? "left"
        #INPUT
    elsif choice.downcase.include? "instructions"
        instructions()
    else
        "That command makes no sense, try again."
    end     
end

Room1()
```

I also assume there are many issues with the code and would be very appreciative of your help, but no worries I am going to keep working on this and make it really fun to play :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the instruction method the last location.

```
def instruction(last_room)
    #do stuff
    last_room.call()
end
```

You would call that function like so:

`instructions(method(:Room1))`, where `Room1` is the name of the method you want to return to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have isn't having instructions return to `Room1` (or `RoomX`).  It'll do that without you doing anything special.  What you need is something like:

```
@room = :Room1
while true
  send(@room)
end
```

and then set the variable `@room` to control which room you're in.

It's not the greatest way in the world to do that, but it'll get you started.